# What is the computational cost of reduced row echelon form (RREF) of a rectangular matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix in $\mathbb{R}$ in which $m\leq n$. Is it possible to find the computational cost of the reduced row echelon form (RREF) of $A$?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible.

Comment: Try few examples and see for yourself, how many field operations are needed.

Comment: See [this excerpt from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency)